# Fastest way to check for comments and processing instructions in XML file and strip whitespace?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xslt

What's the most performant way to check for comments and processing instructions in an XML file and strip unnecessary whitespace in Java?
Processing should fail if either comment or processing instruction is contained in the XML file otherwise all unnecessary whitespace should be removed.

How would the solution look like if processing instructions and comments should be removed as well instead of failing the validation / transformation?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this xslt (version 1.0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|text()|*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()|comment()"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unnecessary whitespace is somewhat tricky sinds in a mixed-content-model whitespace can be significant.